# Angular2 Material ripple effect is not working

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I am using **Angular2 material**. Installed and imported *@angular/material @angular/cdk*.

```
<button md-button>Click me</button>
```

This gives me proper button with respective material CSS. But ripple doesn't work. So I tried adding

```
<button md-button md-ripple>Click me</button>
```

It ends like this
[image]

How to apply ripple effect, is there any proper guidelines.
I wish to achieve ripple effect without using the angular material default themes

Comment: material won't work without a theme. You can create a custom theme if you want, but you will still need a theme

Comment: You don't really need a `md-ripple` directive as by default it should have a ripple. Also, as what @PierreDuc said, you're supposed to add a theme to your app.

Comment: By the way, do you use `@angular/cli`?

Comment: Yes @Edric. I'm using angular/cli

Comment: @PierreDuc material UI alone(css) works fine without theme. But the material animations like ripple effect, side-nav push, etc not working as expected without theme. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the material theme for your app. For a test, in your index.html, add the following link:

```
<link href="https://rawgit.com/angular/material2-builds/master/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" 
rel="stylesheet">
```

if the ripple works, then you can add the theme to your app by following this guideline: [**Theming your Angular Material app**](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but wanted to try without a theme. Now turned towards theme.